# Getting “The input is not of cabinet format” on Discover

Tags: kubuntu, discover-software-center

Discover lists 2 items to update:

"Dell System Firmware"

"UEFI dbx"

I don't know how to search for this on the cli. But if I try to install directly in Discover, I get 2 errors “The input is not of cabinet format”.

How can I fix this?

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
KDE Frameworks Version 5.92.0

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE623.png)

```
> sudo aptitude update
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                   
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease       
Get: 1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease               
Hit https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 11s (10,4 kB/s)    
                                         
> sudo aptitude full-upgrade 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: Done. Thanks. Seems Discover is getting its packages some where else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To solve the issue you can update the firmware manually:

1. Verify you have fwupdmgr installed

```
sudo apt install fwupd
```

2. Look for firmware updates

```
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
```

3. Update

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

4. Reboot to apply changes

Source: [How to update your PC firmware on Linux with LVFS and fwupd](https://www.sindastra.de/p/1416/how-to-update-your-pc-firmware-on-linux-with-lvfs-and-fwupd)